# Admob ad under a view

Tags: android, admob, adview

I want to add an admob ad under a view so it will be hided.

So admob still acts as it's showing ?

```
<view hidden>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</view>
```

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 1):

you can use FrameLayout for laying views on top of each other, for example see below code :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <View
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

in this layout the second view (the view with white background called topView) is on top, and first view (the view with black background called hiddenView) goes behind second view

Comment: @yowovogu this is the general logic for showing two view over each other, but i'am not sure that AdMob view will act as showing in this case, you can test it, btw if this answer solves your problem or helps you, i would be thankful for upvote and accept the answer :), happy coding ;)